# Resource is not loading in executable Spring boot jar - How executable jar loads resources?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to run executable boot spring jar based on documentation provided [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html). I am expecting the resources will be copied to the executable jar on running

```
mvn clean package
```

Here is how I am running the .jar under my project folder

```
./my-application.jar
```

In my project I have a batch process that is running on startup where I am trying to load a resource defined under

```
src/main/resources/batch/request_customers.csv
```

Here is how I am loading the resource
**application.properties**

```
data.customers.input=classpath:batch/request_customers.csv
```

**class**

```
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;
@Component
public class DataManager {

    @Value("${data.customers.input}")
    private String usersExistingData;

    public File jsonCustomerData() throws FileNotFoundException {
        return  ResourceUtils.getFile(usersExistingData);
    }


}
```

**error log**

```
s]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.groupon.batch.CustomerItemReader]: Factory method 'reader' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [batch/request_customers.csv] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/Users/xxx/projects/myproject/target/myproject-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/batch/request_customers.csv; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'job' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/batch/BatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'job' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'step1' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/batch/BatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'step1' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reader' defined in class path resource
```

**I also tried following path**

```
data.customers.input=src/resources/batch/request_customers.csv
data.customers.input=batch/request_customers.csv
```

When I run application using my IDE and spring plugin to resources are loaded without any issues.But fails when I run executable jar using ./my-application.jar

- The question is how to make sure all resources are copies to jar when
  I package it ?
- Do I need to do some other configuration to tell maven to copy resources as they are structured ?
- How I can check if resources are packages into jar ? I can not extract jar for some reasons ?

It would be great to know how exactly I can build a executable jar that basically works like an *executable*.

**UPDATE**
the file exists in the jar that should be loaded. I am not loading from an external file path.

```
BOOT-INF/classes/batch/request_customers.csv
```

**Here is the solution**

When you build a jar file and deploy to a path then you need to treat resources as on file system - relative paths will not magically load resources, which is what I was expecting. You have to open as stream and read them. Here is one way to do that

StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

```
BufferedReader inputStream =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resourceloader.getResource(file).getInputStream()));

String line = null;

while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null){
    buffer.append(line);
}
```

Comment: have you tried `data.customers.input=classpath:/batch/request_customers.csv`. Note the '/' before classpath

Comment: if you even put / it is ignored. I tried batch/request_customers.csv but didn't work.

Comment: Can you confirm that csv file is included in packaged Jar file

Comment: How I can do that ?

Comment: open `/Users/xxx/projects/myproject/target/myproject-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar' in any application that supports zip file like WinZip or 7Zip or Archive Utility if on mac. Navigate inside file in /BOOT-INF/classes/batch/ and see if file is available or not

Comment: The path was correct. So maybe "classpath:" should be omitted here? `data.customers.input=batch/request_customers.csv` (do not think so).

Comment: @JoopEggen when I use batch/request_customers.csv then I am getting error Factory method 'reader' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /private/var/folders/xd/zgshv47j25n46sb_q5ctnyvnnqxz63/T/tomcat-docbase.8410541815829386312.9000/batch/request_customers.csv (No such file or directory);

Comment: So classpath: is needed.

Comment: with classpath: looks like the path is correct but still getting "file can not found". I guess it has to do with how the "executable jar" loads resources and works

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot get a file reference because the file is within a jar (not the filesystem).

The best you can do is read it as a stream using:

```
ResourceUtils.getURL(usersExistingData).openStream()
```

Comment: the file is on the class path within the jar. I am using relative path

Comment: It's not a file though, you can't simply refer to a resource with in a java as using a file object.

Comment: sorry for negative point but it was a mistake. Please edit I will change the point.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `ResourceUtil`, consider using `ResourceLoader` as stated on ResourceUtil doc

```
Consider using Spring's Resource abstraction in the core package for handling all kinds of file resources in a uniform manner. org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader's getResource() method can resolve any location to a org.springframework.core.io.Resource object, which in turn allows one to obtain a java.io.File in the file system through its getFile() method.
```

So your class should be something like this:

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
@Component
public class DataManager {

    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader resourceloader;

    @Value("${data.customers.input}")
    private String usersExistingData;

    public File jsonCustomerData() throws IOException{
        return  resourceloader.getResource(usersExistingData).getFile();
    }


}
```

Comment: can you remove code formatting for second line. its difficult to read it in that way

Comment: Note that using ResourceLoader you need to have ApplicationContext, this won't work if you need to load resources before Spring boot application starts.